# Bookdown not minimizing block headers/sections when clicking on them in table of contents

Tags: r, bookdown

When I use the bookdown package to generate an html book it exports it with every section header already expanded in the "table of contents" along the left side. When clicking on them it navitates correctly, but does not minimize a section when double clicking it. For an example of how I want it to work check out https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/applications.html. If you click "5 Applications" it will minimize/maximize the sub sections.

I wonder if something is wrong with the (mostly untouched YAML _output file), posted below.

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: none
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" 
target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/edit/master/%s
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

Comment: What is your web browser? IE might be problematic.

Comment: @Yihui I'm using the latest stable version of Chrome.

Comment: @Yihui search also doesn't do anything when clicking the search icon. Not sure if it's related.

Comment: I know its old, but since this is unsolved...When I open the link in the OP's question, the sections are already expanded and clicking on "5 Applications" doesn't minimize/maximise subsections.  So I believe this browser related, not YAML/Bookdown.